# ASP.NET Core - Serve both API and SPA from the same port

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Okay, trying to create a website with **ASP.NET Core** and **Angular**, and here is my question: how to serve both **Angular** and **API** from the same port? I mean, if the **URL** starts with `/api/`, then **ASP.NET** should call one of my controllers, else - return an **Angular** page. Is there a way of achieving this? I've found some solutions on how to serve multiple SPAs, but it didn't really help me...

Now my code looks like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp");

    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: it should already working like that with the code you have put. what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @CodingMytra, when I added UseSpa, my controllers stoped working. I mean, I had a standard weather controller, it worked fine, okay. But after adding Angular ASP.NET returns an Angular page on /weatherforecast url, but not the controller's response. The same goes for controllers which URL starts with api/

Comment: you need to look into proxy.config.js file in your angular project. you need to configure a proxy.config.js for your API calls.

Comment: @CodingMytra, okay, still doesn't work. now I have "pending" status for my js http requests and the browser window is stuck on loading as well...

Comment: can you post what have you changed in proxy.config.json file

Comment: hope you followed [this](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) for proxy configuration

Comment: @CodingMytra, I've tried all possible configurations with targeting http and https, "secure" false and true, path like "api/", "api/*"....

can you check [this](https://github.com/llem00n/spa-test), please?

Comment: if you are using .net 6.0, i would suggest to use "ASP.NET Core with Angular" template. it will do all the necessary things required to serve both frontend and backend on same port. you can refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-create-spa-with-net-6-0-and-angular-13-and-deploy-to-azure/) for more

Comment: @CodingMytra this template is not what I really want.. it creates both Angular and ASP.NET servers and just redirects from ASP.NET to the Angular page

Comment: you can create a sample project using this template and take required settings to make it work in your project.

Comment: hey, have you been able to figure this out?
@CodingMytra , which would be the required settings to make it work?
I tried changing the port of the angular server to be the same as the asp.net service but on doing this, the angular server starts to fail (probably because the port is already taken by the asp.net service)

Answer (score 1):

just add `app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapDefaultControllerRoute());`

before `useSpa();`